# Three-term arithmetic progression modulo $n$

Tags: terminology, arithmetic-progressions

Given five positive integers $a, b, c, d, n$, is it legitimate to call a triple $(a, b, c)$ an arithmetic progression modulo $n$, if $b = a + d \mod n$ and $c = b + d \mod n$?

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to submit a sequence at OEIS, so I was unsure about the title to give.

Comment: You can eliminate $d$ by saying $b-a \equiv c-b \pmod n$